# Looping through XML Files, Parsing Data, and Writing to Dataframe and XLSX File

Tags: python, excel, pandas, xml-parsing

thanks in advance for your help.

I have a script that loops through a directory of xls files (the files are truly XML files), parses the XML data, and writes to XLS. The script works as is.

**What I want to do:**

1. Write the files to a new directory, instead of the same directory
2. Write each file as '.xlsx' instead of '.xls'
3. Write each to dataframe, so that I can later if I want, append each of those dataframes into one excel file, in one sheet

Below is the code that works. It writes to the same directory it pulls files from, and creates XLS files.

```
import os
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import glob

ns = {"doc": "urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet"}


for filepath in glob.iglob(r'...Documents\Python\Current_Period\*.xls'):
    print(filepath)

    tree = ET.parse(filepath)

    root = tree.getroot()

    def getvalueofnode(node):
        """ return node text or None """
        return node.text if node is not None else None


    def main():
        """ main """
        parsed_xml = tree

        data = []
        for i, node in enumerate(root.findall('.//doc:Row', ns)):
            if i > 6:
                data.append({'Account': getvalueofnode(node.find('doc:Cell[1]/doc:Data', ns)),
                            'Total': getvalueofnode(node.find('doc:Cell[2]/doc:Data', ns))})

        return(pd.DataFrame(data))

    output_df = main()
    # print = output_df 

    output_df.to_excel(filepath + '.xls', index=False)
```

**Source Data:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-16"?>
<Workbook xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:o="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office" xmlns:x="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:excel" xmlns:ss="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet" xmlns:html="http://www.w3.org/TR/REC-html40">
  <DocumentProperties xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:office">
    <Author>NetSuite Reports</Author>
    <LastAuthor>NetSuite Reports</LastAuthor>
    <Company>NetSuite</Company>
  </DocumentProperties>
  <Styles>
    <Style ss:ID="company">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" />
      <Font ss:Size="12" ss:Bold="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="subcompany">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" />
      <Font ss:Size="14" ss:Bold="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="error">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" />
      <Interior ss:Color="#f0d0d0" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
      <Font ss:Bold="1" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="header_l">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" />
      <Font ss:Size="7" ss:Bold="1" />
      <Interior ss:Color="#d0d0d0" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="header_r">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Right" />
      <Font ss:Size="7" ss:Bold="1" />
      <Interior ss:Color="#d0d0d0" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="header_c">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Center" />
      <Font ss:Size="7" ss:Bold="1" />
      <Interior ss:Color="#d0d0d0" ss:Pattern="Solid" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="scheckbox">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Center" />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="Default" ss:Name="Normal">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Bottom" />
      <Borders />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" />
      <Interior />
      <NumberFormat />
      <Protection />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s53">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Left" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Dash" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#cccccc" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s52">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="1" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s51">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Right" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0" />
      <NumberFormat ss:Format="&quot;€&quot;#,##0.00" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s50">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Left" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s58">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="2" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Dash" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#cccccc" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s54">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Right" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <NumberFormat ss:Format="&quot;€&quot;#,##0.00" />
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Dash" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#cccccc" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s59">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="1" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Dash" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#cccccc" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s56">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="2" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s57">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="3" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="0" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s55">
      <Alignment ss:Horizontal="Left" ss:Indent="1" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders />
    </Style>
    <Style ss:ID="s60">
      <Alignment ss:Vertical="Center" ss:Horizontal="Left" />
      <Font ss:FontName="Arial" ss:Size="8" ss:Color="#000000" ss:Bold="1" ss:Italic="0" />
      <Borders>
        <Border ss:Position="Top" ss:LineStyle="Dash" ss:Weight="1" ss:Color="#cccccc" />
      </Borders>
    </Style>
  </Styles>
  <Worksheet ss:Name="TrialBalance">
    <Table>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="company" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Parent Company</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="company" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Company Holdings Inc. : Company A  B.V.</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="subcompany" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Trial Balance</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="subcompany" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String">End of Feb 2020</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="subcompany" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String" />
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="subcompany" ss:MergeAcross="1">
          <Data ss:Type="String" />
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="header_l">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Account</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="header_r" ss:MergeDown="0" ss:Index="2">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Total</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s50">
          <Data ss:Type="String">10000 - CASH &amp; CASH EQUIVALENTS</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s51" />
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s52">
          <Data ss:Type="String">10101 - Bank - 9999 - Company A - EUR</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s51">
          <Data ss:Type="Number">1234567.01</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
      <Row>
        <Cell ss:StyleID="s53">
          <Data ss:Type="String">Total - 10000 - CASH &amp; CASH EQUIVALENTS</Data>
        </Cell>
        <Cell ss:Formula="SUM(R[-1]C)" ss:StyleID="s54">
          <Data ss:Type="Number">1234567.01</Data>
        </Cell>
      </Row>
    </Table>
  </Worksheet>
</Workbook>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might help

```py
import os
import pandas as pd
import xml.etree.cElementTree as ET
import glob

def iter_docs(root):
    worksheet = root.find('{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Worksheet')

    table = worksheet.find('{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Table')
    for row in table:
      doc_dict = []
      for cell in row.iter('{urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:spreadsheet}Cell'):
        try:
          doc_dict.append(cell[0].text)
        except IndexError: # no data in cell
          doc_dict.append(None)
      yield doc_dict

for filepath in glob.iglob(r'...Documents\Python\Current_Period\*.xls'):
    print(filepath)

    tree = ET.parse(filepath)

    root = tree.getroot()

    doc_df = pd.DataFrame(list(iter_docs(root)))


    doc_df.to_excel(filepath + '.xlsx', index=False)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer on this. In your answer, would I insert the doc_df = pd.DataFrame within my for loop? If not, I'm not certain how this piece will be able to intake the parsed data.

Comment: sorry, missed adding the iter_docs function definition.  The code should work as is. Also, please add some sample data of the XML file

Comment: Hi Petru, thanks again for the answer. Still confused as to how doc_df  handles and inputs the "main()" function that parses XML data into a dataframe. When I try your code it doesn't seem to work, which points me to the lack of passing through the main() function. I also added in sample data in my original post.

Comment: @trevoraaron , Edited the answer. It works now for your sample data now.

Comment: Hi @petru-tanas thanks for your help. Your solution did work to parse the data, but how can I write the new files to a new folder, or augment the filename after the loop?

Comment: You can edit this line "doc_df.to_excel(filepath + '.xlsx', index=False)" ,  to add other any file path you want, just make sure to add +.xlsx. To create a new folder, this should probably be a separate question. Alse, please consider upvoting helpful answers, and accepting the one most helpful.

Comment: Hi @petru-tanas I went ahead and marked the question as answered, thanks again for your help. I will play around with the script to see if I can get it to work but I do add "XLSX" in the doc_df.to_excel line but the output is still always xls. Furthermore, when I try to read that newly created XLS file using another script and it doesn't work, I have to open the file we created and save as .xls. Any thoughts there?

Comment: It is possible that you do not have the latest version of Mircosoft office, hence xlsx files are concerted to xls